# Rails 4 + Devise: sign_in(user) method not working, does not set current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a checkout for a store. When the form is submitted, this action takes place in my controller

```
def update_billing
  ...
  if @checkout.save
    sign_in(guest_user) #<--
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Success!"
  else
    render 'billing'
  end
end
```

I test this by `raise`ing inside the action and testing it out using better_errors:

```
    >> sign_in(guest_user) if params[:checkout_form][:create_an_account] == "1"
    => #<User id: 8, email: "abc123@yahoo.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$HCv7veSO7LC9Dh1tKD0Jbe57Pz6lAsiZgfIiWOys7bF...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 6, current_sign_in_at: "2014-06-04 19:45:36", last_sign_in_at: "2014-06-04 19:29:48", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2014-06-04 18:50:29", updated_at: "2014-06-04 19:45:36", guest: false, guest_email: "guest_140190782975@example.com">
    >> current_user
    => #<User id: 8, email: "abc123@yahoo.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$HCv7veSO7LC9Dh1tKD0Jbe57Pz6lAsiZgfIiWOys7bF...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 6, current_sign_in_at: "2014-06-04 19:45:36", last_sign_in_at: "2014-06-04 19:29:48", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2014-06-04 18:50:29", updated_at: "2014-06-04 19:45:36", guest: false, guest_email: "guest_140190782975@example.com">

    >> session["warden.user.user.key"]
    => [[8], "$2a$10$HCv7veSO7LC9Dh1tKD0Jbe"]
```

However, when I go back to localhost:3000/ , `current_user` becomes `nil` again:

```
    >> session["warden.user.user.key"]
    => nil
    >> current_user
    => nil
```

Doesn't sign_in(guest) user set the session variables so that `current_user` will "persist" across requests?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you modified session_store.rb?  You may want to check the domain parameter there.

Comment: Nope. Should I modify it?

Comment: Does it keep a current_user on a standard devise login page if you go to /users/sign_in or /users/sign_up

Comment: Yeh everything works fine when I sign up using the devise form

Comment: Hey @emcanes I figured it out. In my `@checkout.save` form object, I update the `guest_user`s attributes and save it. I think devise has to sign in the most recent version of `guest_user`, so I had to add a `guest_user.reload` before `sign_in(guest_user)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Edmund you saved my life. You should write a proper answer to this.

Comment: @Edmund I'm having the same issue.  It looks like your solution was to update the guest_user s attributes and save it.  What do you exactly mean by this?  My model is user, so what attributes do I need to update?  Thanks,

Comment: @user2974739 just made an answer to this post, essentially the answer is to call the `reload` method on your user before signing in

Comment: @Edmund I tried reload, but it still doesn't work.  

user.reload
sign_in_and_redirect user

{"warden.user.user.key"=>[[5296], "$2a$10$tP6gld0Dtv4.kp2GnGr3Eu"]}

But, then it becomes nil when coming back to localhost:3000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. In my `@checkout` form object, I update the `guest_user`s attributes and save it when I call `@checkout.save`. I think devise has to sign in the most recent version of guest_user, so I had to add a `guest_user.reload` before `sign_in(guest_user)`

In short, reload your user (`user.reload`) before signing it in.

Comment: thank you for this! this also worked signing in a user from a controller on rails 3.2.6 w/ devise 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

+1 thing to add. There is a setting in initialisers/devise which may lead to sign_in unexpected behaviour:

config.skip_session_storage

if you try to signin inside action configured to be skipped, then you will not be able to do this.